# No module named 'openpyxl' - Python 3.4 - Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.4, openpyxl

I installed `openpyxl` with

```
$ pip install openpyxl
```

when I try the command

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
from openpyxl import Workbook
ImportError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

I am using Python 3.4 and Ubuntu 14.04, 32-bit OS type

Comment: You install it for `python2`, use `pip3 install  openpyxl`.

Comment: In ubuntu both python 2.x and 3.x are installed. The default keyword `python` refers to python 2.x. To use python 3 you need to use `python3` and `pip3` as stated by @zetysz.

Comment: @Kenly Thank you very much for your comment. My problem is solved.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

@zetysz and @Manish already fixed the problem. I am just putting this in an answer for future reference:

- **`pip`** refers to Python **2** as a *default* in Ubuntu, this means that `pip install x` will install the module for Python **2** and **not for 3**
- **`pip3`** refers to Python **3**, it will install the module for Python **3**

Comment: Please be careful, newer versions of Ubuntu may have Python 3 as the default

Answer (score 81):

If you don't use conda, just use :

```
pip install openpyxl
```

If you use conda, I'd recommend :

```
conda install -c anaconda openpyxl
```

instead of simply `conda install openpyxl`

Because there are issues right now with conda updating (see [GitHub Issue #8842](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8842)) ; this is being fixed and it should work again after the next release (conda 4.7.6)

Comment: Simple 
conda install openpyxl 
seems to be working at this moment (Feb 2023, MS Windows)

Answer (score 22):

In order to keep track of dependency issues, I like to use the [conda installer](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/index.html), which simply boils down to:

```
conda install openpyxl
```

Answer (score 12):

You have to install it explixitly using the python package manager as

1. pip install openpyxl for Python 2
2. pip3 install openpyxl for Python 3

Comment: That's exactly what [@ManishGupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4349666/manish-gupta) said.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem solved using instead of pip install :

```
sudo apt-get install python-openpyxl
sudo apt-get install python3-openpyxl
```

The sudo command also works better for other packages.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using Python3, then install:

```
python3 -m pip install --user xlsxwriter
```

This will run pip with the appropriate version of Python3. If you run bare pip3 and have many versions of Python install, it will still fail leading to more confusion.

The --user flag will allow to install as a regular user and no require root.

Comment: Is it more compatible with python 3 or is just your preference? I'm stuck with an openpyxl bug, works fine on windows, but not on Ubuntu server...

Comment: Like I said above, it's more precise than using pip or pip3; it works on all platforms equally well. What's the nature of your problem? What did you see when you ran the above command? What errors are you getting when you try to use this library?

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me:

```
pip uninstall openpyxl
pip install openpyxl
```

Or you can also try

```
pip3 uninstall openpyxl
pip3 install openpyxl
```

If you are using notebooks such as `google-colab`, `jupyter-notebook`, `etc` you can try this:

```
!pip uninstall openpyxl
!pip install openpyxl
```

Or using `pip3`

```
!pip3 uninstall openpyxl
!pip3 install openpyxl
```

Then you may need to restart your notebook if you are using a notebook.

Answer (score 4):

This work for me in Windows, if you want to export or read from Excel

```
pip install openpyxl
pip install --user xlsxwriter
pip install xlrd==1.2.0
```

Answer (score 3):

I still was not able to import 'openpyxl' after successfully installing it via both conda and pip. I discovered that it was installed in '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', so this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59861933/10794682 worked for me:

```
import sys 
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages')
```

Hope this might be useful for others.

Comment: None of the other solution I found worked for me in a Python 3.8 venv
I used the following:
```import sys 
sys.path.append('./env/lib/python3.8/site-packages')
```

Answer (score 1):

Open PyCharm Package and install OPENPYXL. Its working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What worked with me, including many of the above solutions, is to work in with venv, pip install all the requirements in the new virtual environment and run the program.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31513864)