# Save in a new sheet but keep the old sheet in excel using pandas

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I found this link and tried the example: [how-to-save-a-new-sheet-in-an-existing-excel-file-using-pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370977/how-to-save-a-new-sheet-in-an-existing-excel-file-using-pandas)

It does not keep the previous sheets. Is there any way to keep the original sheets?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `append_df_to_excel()` helper function, which is [defined in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38075046/5741205).

**NOTE:** this function requires `openpyxl` module

Usage examples:

```
append_df_to_excel('d:/temp/test.xlsx', df)

append_df_to_excel('d:/temp/test.xlsx', df, header=None, index=False)

append_df_to_excel('d:/temp/test.xlsx', df, sheet_name='Sheet2', index=False)

append_df_to_excel('d:/temp/test.xlsx', df, sheet_name='Sheet2', index=False, startrow=25)
```