# Create multiple dataframes using a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I am trying to make `dataframes` from all the info for all the symbols separately. i.e. `df_ACC`,`df_SBIN` and so on. Write these `dataframes` to `excel` in separate `sheets` naming the sheets according to the symbol being used.

The file generated from the below code is just getting the last `dataframe` i.e. `JUSTDIAL`. While I can't find the `dataframes` other than the last one that also only by `df_name` and not `df_JUSTDIAL` which was my intent.

```
start_time = time.time()
#The solution to second problem I listed
path = r"C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\Data\Fut Data"
opt_fut_excel_file = r'\fo_data_' + str(datetime.date.today()) + ".xlsx"
f_path = path+opt_fut_excel_file
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f_path, engine='xlsxwriter')
fut_data.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='futures', index=False)
#Please add writer.save() at the point where writing to excel is finished.
symbols = ['ACC','SBIN','PNB','JUSTDIAL']
for symbol in symbols:
    print(symbol)
    opt_url1 = 'https://www.nseindia.com/marketinfo/companyTracker/mtOptionKeys.jsp?companySymbol='
    opt_url3 = '&indexSymbol=NIFTY&series=EQ&instrument=OPTSTK&date=-'
    url = opt_url1 + symbol + opt_url3
    raw_page = requests.get(url).text
    soup = bs(raw_page, "lxml")
    if len(raw_page) > 0:
        print(symbol + str(len(raw_page)))
        table = soup.findAll('table')[1]
        test_tab = []
        for row in table.findAll('tr'):
             test_tab.append(([tr.text for tr in row.findAll('td')]))
             # print(len(test_tab))
        try:
            del test_tab[0]
            del test_tab[0]
            del test_tab[0]
            del test_tab[0]
            del test_tab[0]
            del test_tab[0]
            del test_tab[0]
            del test_tab[0]
            del test_tab[0]
            column_names = test_tab[0]
            del test_tab[0]
            # df_name = 'df_' + symbol
            # print(df_name)
            # df_name = pd.DataFrame(test_tab,columns=column_names)
            # opt_fut_excel_file = 'fo_data_' + str(datetime.date.today()) + ".xlsx"
            # df_name.to_excel(opt_fut_excel_file, sheet_name=symbol)
        except:
            print("There was an exception in list del with symbol " + symbol)
             pass
        df_name = 'df_' + symbol
        print(df_name)
        df_name = pd.DataFrame(test_tab, columns=column_names)
        #print(df_name)
        #opt_fut_excel_file = 'fo_data_' + str(datetime.date.today()) + ".xlsx"
        df_name.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=symbol)
    raw_page = 0
#Solution to second problem, this line needs to be there for the file to be saved
writer.save()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

----I believe the question to be not a duplicate because-----

The two-fold question is as follows:

1- Why is the above code not generating multiple `dataframes` with different names?

2- SOLVED - Why are the sheets not getting created while the last one is being generated? @JonClements comment made me get to the answer for this. I have updated the question and code to reflect the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save a new sheet in an existing excel file, using Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370977/how-to-save-a-new-sheet-in-an-existing-excel-file-using-pandas)

Comment: I don't believe it is a duplicate. I am unable to create multiple dataframes for some reason.

Comment: What is with all that `del test_tab[0]` stuff... Have you tried running the code either without a try/except or without such as a bare exception which'll catch *everything* - your code is masking what's causing the error there... Anyway - the link above shows how you're supposed to save multiple sheets to the same workbook - you don't appear to have anything similar to that in your code...

Comment: @JonClements Thanks, that was what I was unclear about. Still dont know how to go about it.

Comment: You're always over-writing the workbook - so only the last copy of the workbook exists.... If you look at the example in the link above - you create an instance of a `writer` object, and re-use that instead of a filename...

Comment: @JonClements Thank you. That was it. Still trying to figure out how to generate multiple `dataframe`'s though.

Comment: `df_name` is just a variable name, It's not important. If you really care about it, use code `locals()[df_name] = pd.DataFrame(test_tab, columns=column_names)`, but it's not recommended. Your code `df_name = 'df' + symbol` does not named a variable, It assign to it, and the code `df_name = pd.DataFrame(test_tab, columns=column_names)` replaces the assignment. Hope I explain clearly.