# After insert data to column in pandas, deletes all other sheets

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to insert a list to existing excel sheet and column. I insert the list to the column but after saving the changes it deletes all other sheets because I use `to_excel`:

```
mysel = [2000, 1, 1, 2018, 1, 1]
xl = pd.ExcelFile('C:\HT_Projeler\mm\HidrolojiModeli\proje.xlsx')
df = xl.parse("Sheet1")

df
   Model Giridisi  Değer
0  Başlangıç Yılı   nan
1  Başlangıç  Ayı   nan
2  Başlangıç Günü   nan
3      Bitiş Yılı   nan
4       Bitiş Ayı   nan
5      Bitiş Günü   nan

df["Değer"] = mysel
df.to_excel(xl)
```

How can I edit or insert list only specific column in specific sheet?

Comment: if you want to add a sheet and not remove the existing sheets while writing in excel , use Excelwriter , have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370977/how-to-save-a-new-sheet-in-an-existing-excel-file-using-pandas

Comment: @anky_91 I jut want to ediitng also existing sheet not want to add new sheet

Comment: Then use: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html                                                                                                         >>> writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
>>> df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
>>> df2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2')
>>> writer.save()

Comment: @anky_91 but I have already xlsx file, ExcelWriter create new xlsx file

Comment: you can use as below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
mysel = [2000, 1, 1, 2018, 1, 1]
xl = pd.ExcelFile('C:\HT_Projeler\mm\HidrolojiModeli\proje.xlsx')
df = xl.parse("Sheet1")
df["Değer"] = mysel
import pandas
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook('C:\HT_Projeler\mm\HidrolojiModeli\proje.xlsx')
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('C:\HT_Projeler\mm\HidrolojiModeli\proje.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

df.to_excel(writer, "Sheetname",index=False)

writer.save()
```

Comment: Where is my changes?

Comment: i didnt get you, it didnt work? what is the result? replace the sheetname with your sheetname

Comment: here I use df["Değer"] = mysel to insert list my df. But I didnt see here

Comment: So after you insert the values into the df using  df["Değer"] = mysel , use this code to write into the excel file. :) this is just to write the data which you already have

Comment: but ExcelWriter dont has parse and dataFrame as I can see

Comment: Excelwriter is just used for writing. you can read it back using whatever excel modules you want. There are some limitations in all the excel modules, however this should work, if not let me know where are you getting stuck

Comment: It works but there is something more. It gives additional column which shows like auto-increment index. It comes from dataFrame probably. Here is the image: https://ibb.co/mZvfXp. I dont have first column normally

Comment: Check the code now, i added index=False while writing the data :)