# How do I add information to an excel sheet without deleting the rest in Python?

Tags: python, excel

**Problem**

I need to make a python script that can export information to excel sheet without deleting sheets old information or sheets. See Pseudocode

**Context:**

This function is to be used in conjunction with a web scraper. And should hopefully, be able to extend data to an existing sheet, create a new sheet, and create a new file.

With the help of other questions, I have come really close:
[How to save a new sheet in an existing excel file, using Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370977/how-to-save-a-new-sheet-in-an-existing-excel-file-using-pandas)
But I want the possibility to extend on existing sheets.

**Pseudocode**

```
def OutputDataToExcel(Filename,Sheetname,df): #df is a pandas dataframe
    If Filename and Sheetname exists:
        extend the Sheetname with df (no header)
    elif Filename exists:
        create new sheet with Sheetname
        add df (with header)
    else:
    create new excelfile with Filename
    create new sheet with Sheetname
    add df (with header)
```

**My code so far**

*Some is out commented to focus on the problem*

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

def outputdata(Filename,Sheetname,df):
    #try:
    #will error if file or sheet cannot be found
    #And will extend information to the sheet
    xl1 = pd.read_excel(Filename,Sheetname)
    xl2 = pd.ExcelFile(Filename)
    wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(Filename)
    length = len(xl2.parse(Sheetname))
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(Filename,sheet_name = Sheetname , engine = "openpyxl")
    df.to_excel(writer,Sheetname, startrow=length+1, index=False, header = None)
    writer.book = wb

    writer.save()
    #writer.close()
    #except:
        #try:
            #will error if file cannot be found
            #and will create a new sheet with information
            #wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(Filename)
            #wb.openpyxl.create_sheet(Sheetname)
            #df.to_excel(writer,Sheetname, index=False)
            #writer.save()
            #writer.close()
        #except:
            #writer = pd.ExcelWriter(Filename,sheet_name = Sheetname  , engine = "openpyxl")
            #df.to_excel(writer,Sheetname, index= False)
            #writer.save()
            #writer.close()
```

**The result**

A new sheet is created with the name Sheetname1 and df is added to this sheet, insted of it being added to Sheetname.
If I run it again a new sheet named Sheetname2 and df is then added here...

I hope someone can help me, it's my first question so, please respond both with help or critic on how to present the problem.

Comment: refer this quesion
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074678/append-existing-excel-sheet-with-new-dataframe-using-python-pandas

Comment: I have tried looking at the answer there. And it has inspired a lot of my code.
But I cannot get it to work with more than one sheet. Old sheets are deleted when I use the approach from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074678/append-existing-excel-sheet-with-new-dataframe-using-python-pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it!!
If anyone has any interest, here is the code:

```
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd

def outputdata(Filename,Sheetname,df):
    try:
        xlsx_file = pd.ExcelFile(Filename)
    except:
        xlsxwriter.Workbook(Filename)
        xlsx_file = pd.ExcelFile(Filename)

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(Filename, engine='openpyxl')
    IsSheetThereAlready = False
    for sheet in xlsx_file.sheet_names:
        if sheet == Sheetname:
            df2 = xlsx_file.parse(sheet)
            df2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name= sheet, index=False)
            df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name= sheet, startrow=len(df2)+1, index=False, header=None)
            IsSheetThereAlready = True

        else:
            df2 = xlsx_file.parse(sheet)
            df2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name= sheet, index=False)


    if IsSheetThereAlready is False:
        df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name = Sheetname, index=False)

    writer.save()

    return
```