# export dataframe to csv and not overwrite cells in csv that contains formula

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataframe on python and I would like to export it to an excel file (xlsx). The xlsx file contains cells with formulas (They are blue). the problem is that when I export the dataframe into the xlsx file, the cells are overwrite and the formulas disappear. Is it possible to export the dataframe by specifying only cells that dont contain a formula in the xlsx file can be filled ?

Comment: is it ok if the dataframe is exported to a new sheet of the existing excel?

Comment: If adding a new sheet is ok then see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370977/how-to-save-a-new-sheet-in-an-existing-excel-file-using-pandas