# loop through a list of dataframes in python and wirte each df into different excel sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a large dataset of almost 4 million records. I'd like to export them in excel but since each sheets of an excel file can contain only 1 million records, I decided to split the dataframe and put each subset into an excel sheet. 
I used the below code:

```
df_split = np.array_split(promotion1, 4)
for i in df_split:
i.to_excel("result_promotion1.xlsx", index = False, sheet_name = i)
```

but that raised the below error:
"'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed"

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with `sheet_name = i`. The `sheet_name` argument is expecting a string, but you're passing it the whole dataframe that you're trying to output to Excel.

The easiest way to resolve would probably to omit the argument and use the defaults (`Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, etc.). Alternatively, you could use `enumerate` to easily number the dataframes and split them into several excel files like so:

```
df_split = np.array_split(promotion1, 4)
for index, i in enumerate(df_split):
    filename = "result_promotion" + str(index) + ".xlsx"
    i.to_excel(filename, index = False)
```

Alternatively, this post ([How to save a new sheet in an existing excel file, using Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370977/how-to-save-a-new-sheet-in-an-existing-excel-file-using-pandas)) goes into how to add a new sheet to an existing Excel file using `pd.ExcelWriter`.

Just to explain the error: since `sheet_name` expects a string and you're giving it a different object, pandas will attempt to hash the object to get a unique string representation of it instead. However, since DataFrames are mutable - you can change values in it, unlike a tuple - they cannot be hashed. See [this post](https://inventwithpython.com/blog/2019/02/01/hashable-objects-must-be-immutable/) for a more detailed explanation on why hashable objects must be immutable.

Comment: really appreciate your explanation

Comment: actually I get the below error: "object of type 'int' has no len()"

Comment: more specific : "
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 740, in _check_sheetname
    if len(sheetname) > 31:"

Comment: the len of my df(promotion1) is 3,978,996. so I guess it fit in multiple excel sheets.

Comment: I have also tried to change the type of sheet_name with this code" j.to_excel("result_promotion1.xlsx", index = False, sheet_name = str(i))" but it seems that each iteration, the sheet will overwrite. therefore the final excel has only one sheet with the final splited dataframe.

Comment: Yes, sorry, just edited my answer in response. The issue was that `index` was an integer and not a string. I just changed it such that it saves a new excel file for each split.

Comment: Thanks, however if I could write the all in one file, but different sheets, that would be awesome.