# loop through a splited dataframe and write each of them in different excel sheets using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Recently I have posted a problem regarding writing a spilted dataframe into different excel sheets [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57743568/loop-through-a-list-of-dataframes-in-python-and-wirte-each-df-into-different-exc/57743711?noredirect=1#comment101931861_57743711), and I somehow find an answer which resulted in writing each of them in a separate excel file rather than separate excel sheets. I have also read the recommended post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370977/how-to-save-a-new-sheet-in-an-existing-excel-file-using-pandas) but that also was not much help. I am wondering if I could find a solution to my question and I really feel that it is not that much complicated but since I am new in this field, I could not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining solutions from both the links that you posted, here is the solution

```
# define an excel writer first 
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx", engine = 'xlsxwriter')

df_split = np.array_split(promotion1, 4)
for index, df_sub in enumerate(df_split):
   #print(df_sub.head())
   # save each of your splitted dataframes using excel writer
   df_sub.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'sheet' + str(index))
```

Comment: problem solved:) thanks. however since I am new to python and coding, I am wondering if you could say the difference between using simply df.to_excel() and creating a writer object and using an engine?

Comment: df.to_excel will create new excel file every time you execute it. However, by using writer object you can add new sheets to existing excel file