# How to plot an excel line graph in python from an existing csv?

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I have the following code which takes a csv string and saves it as an excel file.
I would like to plot a line graph out of this csv, excluding some columns and using the only
string column as x axis (all other columns are numbers).
Creating this graph in excel is a simple three steps procedure:

1. Marking the relevant rows
2. Click on instert
3. Click on line chart

However, I couldnt find a way to do it in python.

Here is my code:

```
def save_to_excel(csv, type):
    csv_data_frame = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv))
    excel_file = pd.ExcelWriter(f"{type}_results.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')
    csv_data_frame.to_excel(excel_file, index=False, sheet_name="results")
    with excel_file:
        pass
```

Can anyone assist in finding an elegant way to go about this?

Comment: To better understand your question: You want the graph to be plottet with e.g. matplotlib, or to be exported and written to the excel-file?

Comment: @DataJanitor I'd like to have the graph to be part of the excel file and reside next to the columns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Xlsxwriter charting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58520584/python-xlsxwriter-charting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `add_chart` and `insert_chart` to accomplish this.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "One": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "two": [5,6,7,8],
    }
)

excel_file = "Excel file.xlsx"
sheet_name = "Sheet1"
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine="xlsxwriter")

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]

chart = workbook.add_chart({"type": "line"})

(max_row, max_col) = df.shape

chart.add_series({"values": [sheet_name, 1, 1, max_row, 1]})
chart.add_series({"values": [sheet_name, 1, 2, max_row, 2]})

worksheet.insert_chart(1, 4, chart)

writer.close()
```

This gives:
[image: Screenshot of result: data and chart in Excel]