# how can I add data to a new sheet when it's too long in Python

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

Is there a way to add data to a new excel sheet when it's too long in python ?
I have a dataframe with a lot of rows that do not fit into one excel sheet.

Comment: What library are you using? Pandas?

Comment: yes I should have specified that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered here: [How to save a new sheet in an existing excel file, using Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370977/how-to-save-a-new-sheet-in-an-existing-excel-file-using-pandas)

Essentially, create a new dataframe object and then save it with a name.

```
x4 = np.random.randn(100, 2)
df4 = pd.DataFrame(x4)

df4.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'x4')
```