# Python DataFrame how to replace a tab in an excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace a tab in an excel spreadsheet with an updated version. The sheet contains many tabs.

The following:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Users\Tiki\Desktop\work\VFT Technicals\Production2\dashboard_v2.xlsx',engine="openpyxl", mode ='a') as writer: 
    output_rsi.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='rsi')
```

Creates a new tab. What I am trying to do is REPLACE the currently existing tab in order to update the data..

Using the above without the `mode = 'a'` but that replaces the entire file with just the rsi tab.

I'm very much a beginner in coding,

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/42375263/4985099

Comment: Thanks, but this does the same thing as the code above, as far as I can tell... I want to REPLACE the tab not add another one.

Comment: what about deleting the initial tab then writing the new one