# How can we add sheet to excel workbook with formula?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, excel-formula, formula

I want to add a new sheet to already existing workbook.

Issue I am facing is the workbook has some formulas present in it. On reading workbook with pandas the formulas are removed and I get values.

How can i maintain other sheets of workbook as it is?

kindly help.
Thank you

Comment: Check out this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370977/how-to-save-a-new-sheet-in-an-existing-excel-file-using-pandas

Comment: @sammy hey thank you for recommendation. actually the issue i am facing is as soon as i read my formula filled excel , the formulas are replaced by values. can you suggest how can i avoid that. thank you for your quick response