# Using Openpyxl: How to overwrite all data on specific excel sheet with a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, openpyxl

This should be pretty straight forward, but I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation.

How can I open an excel workbook and clear all data on a specific sheet, and then write the data in a pandas DataFrame to A1 of that sheet?

Thanks!

Comment: what about df to one new sheet, then openpyxl to copy values to the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest and safest, delete and recreate

```
workbook.remove_sheet(sheet_name)
df1.to_excel("file_name", sheet_name=sheet_name)
```

Comment: Gotcha, so there isn't a good way to keep the sheet? I say this, because other sheets reference specific cells for formulas, and I was hoping to keep that intact.

Comment: Puh, what is the default behaviour if you just use the second line, without deleting first?

Comment: When I use df.to_excel("file_name", sheet_name=sheet_name) it overwrites the entire excel workbook, and saves a new workbook with just one sheet with the given sheet name. So it works correctly, but deletes all other sheets in the workbook.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370977/how-to-save-a-new-sheet-in-an-existing-excel-file-using-pandas

Comment: I think that should help you with the keep the other sheets problem

Comment: I have never tried keeping the references, I will take a look at it toniught