# How to split the dataframe and store it in multiple sheets of a excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import default_rng
rng = default_rng(100)
cdf = pd.DataFrame({'Id':[1,2,3,4,5],
                   'customer': rng.choice(list('ACD'),size=(5)),
                   'region': rng.choice(list('PQRS'),size=(5)),
                   'dumeel': rng.choice(list('QWER'),size=(5)),
                   'dumma': rng.choice((1234),size=(5)),
                   'target': rng.choice([0,1],size=(5))
})
```

I would like to do the below

a) extract the data for unique combination of `region` and `customer`. Meaning `groupby`.

b) store them in each sheet of one excel file (based on number of groups)

I was trying something like below but there should be some neat pythonic way to do this

```
df_list = []
grouped = cdf.groupby(['customer','region'])
for k,v in grouped:
    for i in range(len(k)):
        df = cdf[(cdf['customer']==k[i] & cdf['region']==k[i+1])]
        df_list.append(df)
```

I expect my output to be like below (showing in multiple screenshots).

As my real data has 200 columns and million rows, any efficient and elegant approach would really be helpful

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [this solution](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_multiple.html) in loop:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('out.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    
for (cust, reg), v in cdf.groupby(['customer','region']):
    v.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f"DATA_{cust}_{reg}")
        
    # Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Comment: WOW. so fast. will try and update you. upvoted

Comment: but for loop would work for like big dataset of million rows. where the number of groups may be higher\

Comment: @TheGreat - my experience - bottleneck is in function `to_excel`, so looping per groups is no problem.

Comment: @TheGreat - answer was edited.

Comment: @TheGreat - never working with `StyleFrame` :(

Comment: @TheGreat - unfortunately not.

Comment: For the same task, do you know how can we retain the format, font and color of the excel when I create each sheet? Meaning, master file has a certain color, format, font etc. We would like to have exact font, format and color in child file (multiple sheets)? I will link the new post here

Comment: @TheGreat - Unfortunately no experience with `StyleFrame` what is necessary use here.

Comment: Ah okay. we can't do that with excelwriter? etc

Comment: @TheGreat - Honestly no idea. I guess not. Maybe I am wrong, because with excel styles processing I know only basics.

Comment: Do you know whether it is possible to write the above output to a already existing file (`dummy.xlsx`) instead of `out.xlsx` as shown in post?

Comment: @TheGreat - Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42375263/2901002) solution.