# Exporting a pandas dataframe with more than 2 million rows to Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to export a dataframe with more than 2 million rows into Excel. But since Excel's maximum limit is ~1mil rows. All of the data doesn't go through. Is there any way of doing it? Thanks in advance.

`new1.to_csv( "combined.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLXzN.png)

Comment: This is a limitation of Microsoft Excel and has nothing to do with Python. Your code has nothing to do with Excel - it's just creating a CSV which is essentially a flat file limited only by disk space

Comment: Yep, but is there any way of going around it?

Comment: I have already grouped by and made the data as precise as I can. Reducing it further isn't an option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to exceed that limit, as Vlad pointed out, that's a limitation of Excel.

What I think you could do, if that's an option, is writing the data to the same file, different sheets. An example is shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42375263/5621318).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).