# Conda can't import module that's been installed

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, nco

Others have asked about this, but my situation seems slightly different, and none of the suggestions they received worked for me (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65976231/cant-import-package-after-installing-in-a-conda-environment), [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8716), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45386933/cant-import-a-package-installed-in-anaconda)).

I'm using Anaconda Navigator on Windows, and trying to use the "nco" package. I installed it via the Anaconda Navigator, and when (in Spyder) I type `conda list nco` it gives me:

```
conda list nco
# packages in environment at C:\Users\{user}\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
font-ttf-inconsolata      2.001                hcb22688_0  
nco                       5.0.6                h5be7ecf_0    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1            py39haa95532_1
```

However, when I type `import nco` I get

```
import nco
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_21968/3374827941.py", line 1, in <module>
    import nco

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nco'
```

I notice that there is no "nco" folder in my `C:\Users\{user}\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages` folder; the only "nco" files are in `C:\Users\{user}\Anaconda3\pkgs`, which contains `nco-5.0.6-h5be7ecf_0`. I'm not completely sure whether to expect an nco folder in site-packages, but thought I'd mention that there isn't one there there.

I also tried making a new environment, `test` (had just been in `base` before), and installing nco via the navigator, but `conda list nco` gives the same:

```
conda list nco
# packages in environment at C:\Users\{user}\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
font-ttf-inconsolata      2.001                hcb22688_0  
nco                       5.0.6                h5be7ecf_0    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1            py39haa95532_1
```

and import nco still doesn't work.

I've also tried `conda update --all`, which ran quickly and updated nco among others, but doesn't change anything with my issue.

I also tried `conda clean -p`; it ran for 12 hours before I cancelled it just now; it didn't print any output, but I don't know if I'd expect it to.

Finally, I'm just using 1 version of python, and have only recently installed/started using Anaconda.

```
(base) C:\>which python
/cygdrive/c/Users/{user}/Anaconda3/python

(base) C:\>which conda
/cygdrive/c/Users/{user}/Anaconda3/Scripts/conda
```

Any suggestions really appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Conda package `nco`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/nco) refers to [the commandline tool](http://nco.sourceforge.net). The Python bindings to `nco` are provided by [the Conda package `pynco`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pynco). So, you want

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge pynco
```

This will also install the `nco` package.

Answer (score 1):

After installing `pynco`, you can import it like below.

```
from nco import Nco
nco = Nco()
```

Please refer https://github.com/nco/pynco

Comment: Many thanks for this code - this worked for me with pynco installed.