# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl' when i deploy my django app on heroku

Tags: python, django, openpyxl

In my django application I use the openpyxl module to work with excel files. It works perfectly locally but when I deploy on heroku it doesn't work. I have this error:

```
import openpyxl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

My python version 3.8
What can I do to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `openpyxl` in your requirements file and installed by the server?

Comment: Yes i installed it manually on the server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No module named 'openpyxl' - Python 3.4 - Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509198/no-module-named-openpyxl-python-3-4-ubuntu)